# Sibling trust problem

Tags: situation

Amy and Bill are two siblings who share a computer with their parents at home. A maximum of two user accounts can be set up on this computer, so Amy and Bill have to share an account, whilst their parents share the other account.

Several times during the week, one of the siblings is left at home alone as the parents have to work, and the siblings stay for different after-school activities.

The problem here is that Amy and Bill aren’t the closest siblings in the world, so neither of them are really willing to share their account, as one might log on whilst the other isn’t around and change the password to lock the other out of the account. Therefore, neither of the siblings trusts the other to access their account whilst one isn’t keeping a close eye on the other.

The parents do not wish to share their account with the siblings either, as they have important information stored on their computer which they do not want to risk being messed around with.

Is there a possible solution to this problem without the family having to buy a new computer?

[Next part to the problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30376/group-trust-problem)

Comment: Quite honestly, I don't know what tags to put on this, so could someone help me?

Comment: Note that after this is solved, there is an extension to this problem which I shall post.

Comment: Can we set up two virtual machines on the one account, with user settings such that the password can never be changed?

Comment: Lets assume the family aren't tech-savy, and the kids are just kids. There is a simple solution, I can assure you.

Comment: lol I just realised what my rep was, added the logic puzzle tag - only tag that really fits I think

Comment: Is the password change the only security issue? Are they worried about deleting or accessing each other's files, for instance?

Comment: They are. But as long as one is watching the other, then it's fine. (ie. they want to be in the same room when one is using the computer).

Comment: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/30376/group-trust-problem

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil This is absolutely not the type of question the logic puzzle tag is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nobody knows the full password.
>  The password for each account can be formed only if each of the account users fills in "half" (not necesarily half the length...you know what I mean) of the password

Comment: Correct. I shall post the extended version of this next.

Comment: oh boy oh boy....bring it on.

Comment: @QuestionAsker you're on a question hot-streak!

Comment: Unfortunately, they seem to be too easy. Thankfully, I'm pretty sure the extension will not be so.